# Why am I getting a segfault on cin?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cin

I am writing a fairly simple exercise (homework), and most of it works, however it *sometimes* segfaults on cin. Here is the relevant code.

```
int main()
{
  std::string str = "";
  std::cout << "Please select the desired operation:\n";
  std::cout << "(A): Generate Decompositions\n";
  std::cout << "(B): Generate Acceptable Compositions from S1.txt and S2.txt\n";
std::cout << "cout"; //debug statement
  std::cin >> str;
std::cout << "cin"; //debug statement
  std::cout << str;
  char resp = str.at(0);
std::cout << "resp"; //debug statement

...
}
```

I get a segfault on `std::cin >> str` (I know this because of what "debug statements" are output). But the weird thing is, *I only get it when I input 'b'*. If I input 'a', or any word starting with 'a', it works fine. If I enter any letter other than a or b, or anything starting with any other letter than a or b, it exits (as it's supposed to). But if I type in 'b', or any word starting with 'b', it Segfaults. Every single time. Why?

Comment: "I know this because of what "debug statements" are output" You do not have `<< endl` at the end, so some of the output may still be buffered at the time of segfault.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I did not know that, thanks. I will do some more checking

Comment: Are you sure you're not crashing at `char resp = str.at(0)` (and having an exception thrown?).  You might not be seeing the output from the previous two lines at that point due to buffering.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - nope, it's further down. @ dasblinkenlight was right. Still trying to pin down exactly where

Comment: @iamthesgt: debuggers are really good at helping with this kind of thing.

Comment: Okay, I found it. Turned out I was converting a string to an integer improperly, and as a result, a loop was running too long, which caused the segfault. Thanks @dasblinkenlight for pointing out that some of the output may be buffered. If you post that as an answer pointing out why that doesn't make it certain the error is there, I'll accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know this because of what "debug statements" are output"

The code that you posted looks fine.

Since your output statements do not have `<< endl` at the end, some of the output may still be buffered at the time of segfault. Writing out `endl` blocks until the output is flushed, so adding `<< endl` is likely to help you get closer to the actual location of the crash.