# Seg Fault on cin. Tried the endl thing. Lousy at gdb

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, gdb

I getting a strange segfault I don't understand.

```
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ g++ -g all_pairs.cpp 
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ ./a.out
Please enter filename: 
table.txt
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see from the cout staements, it is segfaulting right in `cin>>filename;`  Here's the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
        int n;

        string filename;
        cout << "Please enter filename: " << endl;
        cin >> filename;
        cout << "FLAG FLAG FLAG";

        ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
        if (!fin.is_open()) {
                cout << "ERROR: file not found.  Exiting..." << endl;
                return -1;
        }

        fin >> n;
        vector<Table> tables;
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        fin >> temp;
                        tables[0].data[i][j] = temp;
                }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
                tables.push_back(calc_next_table(tables, i, n));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I really feel like a moron, I have never come across this before.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227680/why-am-i-getting-a-segfault-on-cin), but it didn't solve it.  I even tried gdb (which I don't really know how to use) and all I got was this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401ae8 in std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::operator[] (this=0x0, __n=0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:771
771       { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb) list
766        *  out_of_range lookups are not defined. (For checked lookups
767        *  see at().)
768        */
769       reference
770       operator[](size_type __n)
771       { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
772 
773       /**
774        *  @brief  Subscript access to the data contained in the %vector.
775        *  @param __n The index of the element for which data should be
```

This looks like a vector is doing something funky, but I haven't even declared my vectors yet!  Any ideas?

EDIT:  I like @neilson's answer, but the following is still throwing segfault:

```
        fin >> n;
        vector<Table> tables;
        Table t;
        tables.push_back(t);

        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        fin >> temp;
                        tables[0].data[i][j] = temp;
                }
        }

        cout << "FLAG FLAG FLAG" << endl;
```

Table has one element, a `vector<vector<int>>` called `data`.  Should I post that as well?

Comment: What if you change `cout << "FLAG FLAG FLAG";` to `cout << "FLAG FLAG FLAG" << endl;`? Normally (for some reason) it doesn't actually print anything until the end of the line.

Comment: excellent that got me past cin noow im on to the actual segfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
    fin >> n;
    vector<Table> tables;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    fin >> temp;
                    tables[0].data[i][j] = temp;  // HERE
            }
    }
```

The vector is empty while you access it.

Do

```
tables.push_back(..something..)
```

first.
Like this:

```
    fin >> n;
    vector<Table> tables;
    Table someTable;               // Create a table
    tables.push_back(someTable);   // Put it in the vector
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    fin >> temp;
                    tables[0].data[i][j] = temp;
            }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Since you tell that Table also have a vector, then you need to change:

```
                    tables[0].data[i][j] = temp;
```

to use push_back also.

You can't access elements in a vector unless you added the elements first.

If Table has the member:

```
vector<vector<int>> data;
```

you could maybe do something like:

```
    fin >> n;
    vector<Table> tables;
    Table someTable;               // Create a table
    tables.push_back(someTable);   // Put it in the vector
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tables[0].data.push_back(vector<int>());    // create the i'th vector and insert it
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    fin >> temp;
                    tables[0].data[i].push_back(temp);  // Use push_back
            }
    }
```

Note: I haven't tested this as I'm not near the compiler... but I think something like that would do.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much, its breaking later, where I expected it to now!